# "VARCHAR" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE Students 
(
    stud_id INT(10) UNSIGNED not null,
    stud_name VARCHAR(30) not null,
    stud_phone CHAR(11) not null,
    stud_date_of_birth DATE not null,
    stud_city CHAR(30) not null,
    stud_address CHAR(100) not null,
    stud_postcode SMALLINT UNSIGNED not null,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (stud_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Subjects
(
    subj_code CHAR(6) not null,
    subj_title VARCHAR(30),

    PRIMARY KEY (subject_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Subj_Enrolment
(
    stud_id INT(10) UNSIGNED not null,
    subj_code CHAR(6) not null,
    semester SMALLINT UNSIGNED not null,
    year YEAR not null,
    comment VARCHAR(100) not null,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (stud_id, subj_code, semester, year),
    FOREIGN KEY (stud_id) REFERENCES Students(stud_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subj_id) REFERENCES Subjects(subj_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Grades
(
    stud_id INT(10) UNSIGNED not null,
    subj_code CHAR(10) not null,
    semester SMALLINT UNSIGNED not null,
    year YEAR not null,
    grade CHAR(2) not null,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (stud_id, subj_code, semester, year),
    FOREIGN KEY (stud_id) REFERENCES Students(stud_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subj_code) REFERENCES Subjects(subj_code)
);

ALTER TABLE Students
ADD COLUMN gender CHAR(1) CHECK(gender='m' OR gender='f');

ALTER TABLE Subj_Enrolments
DROP COLUMN comment VARCHAR(100);
```

So on Line 52 or the last line where "DROP COLUMN comment VARCHAR(100);" the error that came up is written on the title, but I do not understand why is this wrong, what mistake am did I cause? I did use VARCHAR for when I am creating my tables but when I want to alter it the first alteration is correct but the second one is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not specify column type with a DROP, only the column name, so :

```
ALTER TABLE Subj_Enrolments
DROP COLUMN comment;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html